# php in_array() with an array as needle producing unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple `in_array()` with an array as needle example below, however I expect that my example should echo;

> match found in the array

Given both needles exist in the haystack. However this code does not produce an echo. I was hoping someone could help me understand why i'm not getting a match here.

```
<?php
$needle =  array('fjord', 'troz');
$haystack =  array('troz', 'zort', 'fran', 'fjord');
if (in_array($needle, $haystack))
{
echo "match found in the array";
}

?>
```

I have read http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php but am unsure why i'm not getting a match.

Comment: Because the needle is an array `in_array()` is looking for an array.

Comment: You would have a match for this haystack: `array(array('foo', 'bar'), array('fjord', 'troz'));` When needle is an array, it doesn't mean consider it a match if all elements in needle also exist in haystack. It means consider it a match if haystack contains an *array* with the exactly the same elements (not more, not less) as needle.

Comment: can you explain why? **update** i just ran with `array(array('foo', 'bar'), array('fjord', 'troz'));` but still no match.

Comment: @Jamie in that example, the haystack is a nested array, and one of those nested arrays is the needle in one of the examples, thus returning a `true`.

Comment: @Jamie, if it didn't match, you made a mistake. Look at Example #3 on the man page.

Comment: Expected result is no match since there is no such $haystack element as your $needle array

Comment: @marekful yes I had made a mistake. Thanks for your comment, I understand now. I am using `in_array()` incorrectly, and I don't think ti will work for my purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the needle is an array `in_array()` is looking for an array in the haystack. The following works:

```
$needle =  array('fjord', 'troz');
//$haystack =  array('troz', 'zort', 'fran', 'fjord');
$haystack = array(array("fjord","troz"), array("foo","bar"));
if (in_array($needle, $haystack))
{
echo "match found in the array";
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b373b4435ebd17d190bf143db835ba3f6c9a939)

Comment: accepted as this answers the question. `array_intersect()` is the correct function to use in my case, as suggested by @rolfv1

Answer (score 13):

To avoid loops you can use `array_intersect()`:

```
if(count(array_intersect($needle, $haystack)))
```

Comment: Thanks @rolfv1 `array_intersect()` is the correct function to use for my purposes.